# Enterprise Grade PHP Application Servers

Tags: untagged

I am on the lookout for a commercial PHP (application!) server that comes with Vendor support to use with enterprise scale applications.

I know that it quite easy to put everything together myself (Apache + Fast CGI + PHP + APC + xdebug etc.,). But commercial production support is one of the main requirements for us and also the ease of upgrading the platform. It will be ideal to have a single vendor providing all dependent packages that are pre-tested to work with each other.

I have so far identified Zend Server & Sun Glassfish web stack (http://www.sun.com/software/webstack/index.xml).

I would like to hear if anyone has experience using these products and their feedback on the same. Are there any other similar products out there that you would like to recommend?

P.S.: I earlier asked this question in StackOverflow.com. But thought this site is a better place for this.

Comment: I suspect many people will be of the opinion that PHP itself isn't 'enterprise grade'.

Comment: @Zoredache: I know. That is a separate debate altogether. However, I think more than one compnay has demonstrated successfully that PHP is ready for the enterprise. The oldest one being the Wikimeda Foundation.(wikipedia.org).

Answer (score 1):

you can as well consider unortodox approach and check out [caucho](http://caucho.com/)'s offer. it's called [quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), it's php implemented in java. they claim to have very high performance.

i have not used quercus but i use on daily basis resin - caucho's java appserv [ that is underlaying layer for quercus as well ] and i'm very happy with it. i use free version of it, i'm not paying customer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Quercus looks quite interesting. As someone who has had happy memories using resin in the past, I will be happy to test quarcus. But I doubt if I will run into to any compatibility issues going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with the products you mentioned but I wanted to add that any commercially supported server Linux distribution will also support both Apache and PHP.

So both Novell Suse and Red Hat Enterprise Linux could also be considered.

Comment: To take an analogy what I am after is the MySQL enterprise edition and not the MySQL Community Edition that is shipped along with the OS. 

While it is true that RH/Suse ship with components required for a LAMP stack, what I am after is a more complete product (with features like op-code caching etc.). 

Also, The OS vendors are usually very late in packaging the latest versions of PHP for their enterprise os versions. For example RHEL 5 still only ships with php 5.1.x. Development has long stopped on that branch and RH is still backporting security fixes, which is not an ideal situation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't strictly mention you want a solution to self host but is it worth talking to one of the 'managed hosting' companies, [eapps](http://eapps.com), rackspace.com etc etc, about what your after.
This means your no longer worrying about the servers and can concentrate on what your really meant to be doing.