# Choice of PHP Application Server

Tags: php, glassfish, sun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enterprise Grade PHP Application Servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/25968/enterprise-grade-php-application-servers)

Hi Folks,

I am on the lookout for a commercial PHP (application!) server that comes with Vendor support to use with enterprise scale applications.

I know that it quite easy to put everything together myself (Apache + Fast CGI + PHP + APC + xdebug etc.,). But commercial production support is one of the main requirements for us and also the ease of upgrading the platform. It will be ideal to have a single vendor providing all dependent packages that are pre-tested to work with each other.

I have so far identified Zend Server (http://www.zend.com/products/server/) & Sun Glassfish web stack (http://www.sun.com/software/webstack/index.xml).

I would like to hear if anyone has experience using these products and their feedback on the same. Are there any other similar products out there that you would like to recommend?

Comment: What OS? Also, Zend Server does not come with xdebug. There are some posts around that try to explain how to make it work, but it involves disabling some other features. It ships with Zend Debugger instead.

Comment: Dup. http://serverfault.com/questions/25968/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just want to use a commerical linxu distribution like RHEL?
There you get a complete web stack (apache, php, mysql) with support from the vendor, Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think your best bet, even though there's no commercial support, is going to be Apache. Not only is it going to be saving you a lot of money, it's also going to be very stable and come with a lot of community based support (stackoverflow, for example). Upgrading the platform is also very easy, especially if you're running a linux distribution like debian, where all you have to do to upgrade all packages on the system (including apache2) is `sudo apt-get upgrade`.